# Spring Boot @Around does not work on javax.jms.MessageListsner.onMessage()

Tags: spring-boot, jms, interceptor, aspect

I'm trying to develop a log interceptor for some methods in our AMQP-Project.
I'm using Springs @Aspect-Annotation and a custom annotation to create a interceptor. Our AMQP-Controller implements the `javax.jms.MessageHandler` interface and overrides the `onMessage(Message)`-Method i want to intercept.

The class has the following signature:

```java
public abstract class AMQPController implements MessageListener {
...
   @Override
   public void onMessage(Message message){
      // application logic
   }
...
}
```

My interceptor looks like this:

```java
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggedInterceptor {

   @Around("execution(public void javax.jms.MessageListener+.onMessage(..))")
   public Object intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
      // application logic
   }
}
```

Every time a new AMQP-Message is triggered the `onMessage()`-Method is triggered but my interceptor does not seem to be triggered.

Does anyone has an idea why?

Greetings from Germany :-)

Comment: There is no `javax.jms.MessageHandler`

Comment: Sorry i meant `javax.jms.MessageListener` (See edited question) :-)

Comment: The method isn't called on an implementation but rather an `abstract` thus super class.

Comment: Hey. Were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it,

@Around(value = "execution (* javax.jms.MessageListener.onMessage(..))")